# First executed of two equivalent LINQ queries always runs slower

Tags: c#, performance, linq, benchmarking

Consider the following two ways of writing this LINQ query:

Option 1:

```
public void MyMethod(List<MyObject> myList)
{
   ...
   var isValid = myList.Where(l => l.IsActive)
                       .GroupBy(l => l.Category)
                       .Select(g => g.Count() > 300) //arbitrary number for the sake of argument
                       .Any();
}
```

Option 2:

```
public void MyMethod(List<MyObject> myList)
{
   ...
   var isValid = myList.Where(l => l.IsActive)
                       .GroupBy(l => l.Category)
                       .Select(g => g.Count()) 
                       .Any(total => total > 300); //arbitrary number for the sake of argument
}
```

I wanted to see if there was any difference in performance between the two so I created a console app (shown below) to compare them.

What's happening is that the query that gets executed first always runs slower and then on subsequent runs they both show as run in 0 milliseconds. I then changed the comparison value to Ticks and got similar results. If I switch the order in which the queries are executed, the new first one now runs slower.

So the question is twofold, why does the first executed query seems to be the slower one? And, is there a way in which I can actually compare the performance of the two?

Here's the testing code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Running test");

    var rnd = new Random();

    for (var i = 0;i < 5; i++)
    {
        RunTest(i, rnd);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void RunTest(int runId, Random rnd)
{
    var list = GetData(rnd);

    var startOne = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    var one = list.Where(l => l.IsActive)
        .GroupBy(l => l.Category)
        .Select(g => g.Count() > 300)
        .Any();

    var endOne = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    var startTwo = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    var two = list.Where(l => l.IsActive)
        .GroupBy(l => l.Category)
        .Select(g => g.Count())
        .Any(c => c > 300);

    var endTwo = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

    var resultOne = (endOne - startOne).Milliseconds;
    var resultTwo = (endTwo - startTwo).Milliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine($"Results for test run #{++runId}");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"Category 1 total: {list.Where(l => l.Category == 1 && l.IsActive).Count()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Category 2 total: {list.Where(l => l.Category == 2 && l.IsActive).Count()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Category 3 total: {list.Where(l => l.Category == 3 && l.IsActive).Count()}");
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine($"First option runs in: {resultOne} ");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Second option runs in: {resultTwo} ");
}

    private static List<MyObject> GetData(Random rnd)
    {
        var result = new List<MyObject>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {                
            result.Add(new MyObject { Category = rnd.Next(1, 4), IsActive = rnd.Next(0, 2) != 0 });
        }

        return result;
    }
}

    public class MyObject
    {
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public int Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your two queries don't check the same thing. The first query says count every group, convert to a list of booleans that are true when the count is over 300, then see if any groups exist, which is the same as `myList.Where(l => l.IsActive).Any()` with a lot of extra work. Your second query asks if a group with a count over 300 exists.

Comment: What is the type of `list` returned by `GetData`? It may be that you are executing something the first time `list` is processed, and not the second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your benchmarking methodology.

First, when you have two `DateTime` values and you compare them by their `TimeOfDay` properties...

```
var startOne = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
// Do some work
var endOne = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var resultOne = (endOne - startOne).Milliseconds;
```

...then you run the risk of getting a *negative* duration if a test were to span a day transition (midnight).  Consider this...

```
DateTime midnight = DateTime.Today;
DateTime fiveSecondsBeforeMidnight = midnight - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
DateTime fiveSecondsAfterMidnight  = midnight + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

Console.WriteLine($"Difference between DateTime  values: {fiveSecondsAfterMidnight - fiveSecondsBeforeMidnight}");
Console.WriteLine($"Difference between TimeOfDay values: {fiveSecondsAfterMidnight.TimeOfDay - fiveSecondsBeforeMidnight.TimeOfDay}");
```

...which prints...

```
Difference between DateTime  values: 00:00:10
Difference between TimeOfDay values: -23:59:50
```

Instead, you can fix this bug and simplify your code by comparing the `DateTime` values directly...

```
var startOne = DateTime.Now;
// Do some work
var endOne = DateTime.Now;
var resultOne = (endOne - startOne).Milliseconds;
```

This can be further improved, however, by using the [`Stopwatch` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch), which is more accurate than comparing `DateTime` values and specifically designed for this purpose...

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Do some work
TimeSpan resultOne = stopwatch.Elapsed;

stopwatch.Restart();
// Do some work
TimeSpan resultTwo = stopwatch.Elapsed;
```

Second, the [`TimeSpan.Milliseconds` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.milliseconds) returns only the milliseconds *component* of the `TimeSpan` value.  To get the `TimeSpan` value *in milliseconds* you want the [`TotalMilliseconds` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds).  Consider the difference here...

```
TimeSpan value1 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
TimeSpan value2 = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(900);

Console.WriteLine($"     value1.Milliseconds: {value1.Milliseconds}");
Console.WriteLine($"value1.TotalMilliseconds: {value1.TotalMilliseconds}");
Console.WriteLine($"     value2.Milliseconds: {value2.Milliseconds}");
Console.WriteLine($"value2.TotalMilliseconds: {value2.TotalMilliseconds}");

Console.WriteLine($"value1 is {(value1.Milliseconds      < value2.Milliseconds      ? "less" : "greater")} than value2 (by Milliseconds)");
Console.WriteLine($"value1 is {(value1.TotalMilliseconds < value2.TotalMilliseconds ? "less" : "greater")} than value2 (by TotalMilliseconds)");
```

...which prints...

```
     value1.Milliseconds: 500
value1.TotalMilliseconds: 1500
     value2.Milliseconds: 900
value2.TotalMilliseconds: 900
value1 is less than value2 (by Milliseconds)
value1 is greater than value2 (by TotalMilliseconds)
```

Comparing the `Ticks` property, like you did, would be another way around this, or you could just store the time difference as a `TimeSpan` without picking off one of its properties and let string formatting handle the smaller components...

```
TimeSpan resultOne = endOne - startOne;
TimeSpan resultTwo = endTwo - startTwo;

// ...

Console.WriteLine($"First option runs in: {resultOne:s\\.ffffff} seconds");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine($"Second option runs in: {resultTwo:s\\.ffffff} seconds");
```

Finally, I ran your code and see the same results you did: the first runs are non-zero and subsequent runs are zero.  My guess would be that the first runs take longer because your code has not yet been JIT optimized.  Even those "slow" first runs take only a matter of milliseconds to complete because your list is only a thousand items long.  Benchmark runs that short do not provide meaningful comparisons.

After making the changes described above and increasing the size of the `List<>` returned by `GetData()` to 10 million items, each run takes several seconds, with the first option being several milliseconds faster in the first run and 25-125 milliseconds slower in subsequent runs.

Instead of rolling your own benchmark code, you might consider using a library like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/).  It handles details such as figuring out how many runs to perform, "warming up" your code to ensure it's already been optimized, and calculating statistics for you.

Comment: CPU frequency ramp-up to max turbo is another factor that might be hurting the first but not 2nd.  IDK if it matters that the first test will page-fault some heap memory and then return it to a free-list, so allocation in the 2nd test can be much faster.  That's probably not enough to explain whole milliseconds (millions of clock cycles).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can accurately compare the performance of your two options using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). This becomes a simple test script to setup.

```
void Main()
{
    var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<CollectionBenchmark>();
}

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class CollectionBenchmark
{
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private List<MyObject> _list = new List<MyObject>();

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void GlobalSetup()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            _list.Add(new MyObject { Category = rnd.Next(1, 4), IsActive = rnd.Next(0, 2) != 0 });
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void OptionOne()
    {
        var one = _list.Where(l => l.IsActive)
            .GroupBy(l => l.Category)
            .Select(g => g.Count() > 300)
            .Any();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void OptionTwo()
    {
        var two = _list.Where(l => l.IsActive)
            .GroupBy(l => l.Category)
            .Select(g => g.Count())
            .Any(c => c > 300);
    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
}
```

This yielded the following results on my machine:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.14, OS=Windows 10.0.17134
Intel Core i5-6300U CPU 2.40GHz (Skylake), 1 CPU, 4 logical and 2 physical cores
Frequency=2437498 Hz, Resolution=410.2567 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.6.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3324.0
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.6.2 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 64bit RyuJIT-v4.7.3324.0


|    Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
|---------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|-------:|----------:|
| OptionOne | 36.73 us | 0.7491 us | 1.9202 us | 8.4839 |  13.13 KB |
| OptionTwo | 36.37 us | 0.6993 us | 0.8053 us | 8.4839 |  13.13 KB |
```

The memory allocated is the same. Considering the benchmark measures a time difference in a fraction of a microsecond, there is no practical difference in the performance of either.